# Stack Overflow jobs - can't reapply - Internal Server Error

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

When I'm trying to reapply to the job I applied 102 days ago for testing purposes, but this time with my normal resume, I am getting an error:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened! We apologize for any inconvenience, but
> an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded
> and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional
> information about this error, do so at our feedback site,
> https://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Why is that? What can I do about it? It is still available and it says it was posted yesterday.

Comment: Can you let me know what job produced the error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/147424/front-end-software-engineer-global-health-data-dhis2

Comment: still no solution

Comment: Sorry! I didn’t see your reply. I’ll look into this first thing in the morning.

Comment: Still no fix :)

Comment: Flash, I sent you an email because I need more details about the error. I can't reproduce the issue, looks like it's specific to how you're applying on your account. FYI, as a workaround, you can always re-apply in incognito mode.

Comment: I did answer to your email twice. Maybe it's in the spam?